# css break words into new lines and becomes off positioned

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple tooltip without the need for js.

I'm wondering what the best approach is. I want dynamic text to be able to fit in a tooltip container smoothly, responsively on top of its container, the issue with the current code is that it doesn't stretch on its own, it breaks words into new lines which changes the height of the whole thing and then the positioning is off and it overlaps its container.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
  
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
}

td:hover div span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    something
      <div>
        <span>
          text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>    
    <td>
    something
      <div>
        <span>
          some long text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like? Let me know.

If you want your tooltip above hover item, add `bottom:100%` to tooltip element.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;  
  /*style to show it better to you*/
  display:block;
  margin-right:50px;
  float:left;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left:50%;
  width:60px;
  margin-left:-30px;
}

span {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

td:hover div span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      something
      <div>
        <span>
          text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      something
      <div>
        <span>
          some long text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ahhhhh. white-space: nowrap; fixed it. forgot about that. can you explain how overflow, text-overflow and word-wrap would also be of use for something similar? thanks

Comment: See my updated answer, for better working demo. As you can see, if the tooltip text is too long, it will add  `...`.  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is doing this. So in this case, your tooltip will always be one line. Ofcourse you could make your tooltip wider, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to break text in `tooltip` you can use `white-space: nowrap`. You can also use `transform: translate()` to position tooltip in middle of `td` [`With arrow`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/165/)

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
  
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

td:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>something<span>text</span></td>    
    <td>something<span>some long text</span></td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor.<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you want `tooltip` to be same size as `td` you can use `width: 100%`

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
  
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

td:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>something<span>text</span></td>    
    <td>something<span>some long text</span></td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor.<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use `:after` pseudo element to add small arrow under tooltip

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
  
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

span:before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  content: '';
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

td:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>something<span>text</span></td>    
    <td>something<span>some long text</span></td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor.<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
  
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

td:hover div span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    something
      <div>
        <span>
          text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>    
    <td>
    something
      <div>
        <span>
          some long text
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try using white-space: nowrap;